# Endless loop in Quicksort algorithm when array has two instances of the same value

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting, infinite-loop, quicksort

I've been trying to write up a Quicksort function in Visual Basic as practice. It was simple enough to do and it works fine for arrays that don't have the same number appearing twice. But as soon as that happens, the second iteration of the loop advancing the left pointer toward the right pointer gets stuck in an endless loop and I can't for the life of me figure out why that happens.

If anyone has an idea why it's stuck, I'd appreciate the help. Here's the code:

```
Public Function Partition(ByVal a As Integer(), ByVal left As Integer, ByVal right As Integer)

    Dim temp As Integer

    Do While left <> right

        Do While (a(left) < a(right)) And (left <> right)
            left = left + 1                
        Loop

        temp = a(left)
        a(left) = a(right)
        a(right) = temp

        Do While (a(left) < a(right)) And (left <> right)
            right = right - 1                
        Loop

        temp = a(left)
        a(left) = a(right)
        a(right) = temp

    Loop

    Return left
End Function

Sub QuickSort(ByVal a As Integer(), ByVal left As Integer, ByVal right As 
Integer)

    If left < right Then
        Dim position As Integer = Partition(a, left, right)
        QuickSort(a, left, position - 1)
        QuickSort(a, position + 1, right)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I replaced the `VBA` tag with `VB.NET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens whenever `a(left)` and `a(right)` are the same. After you swap them, they are still the same so you swap again and again.
To avoid that situation you need to

1.Replace the loop below:

```
Do While (a(left) < a(right)) And (left <> right)
            left = left + 1                
        Loop
```

with this:

```
Do While (a(left) <= a(right)) And (left <> right)
            left = left + 1                
        Loop
```

in order to put the elements equal to the pivot, to its left side

2.Add a one-step progress after the second loop (but only for the case when the iterators do not point at the same element which implies end of partitioning):

```
  Do While (a(left) < a(right)) And (left <> right)
            right = right - 1                
        Loop

        temp = a(left)
        a(left) = a(right)
        a(right) = temp

        If left <> right
           left = left + 1
        End if
```

So the modified function looks like following:

```
Public Function Partition(ByVal a As Integer(), ByVal left As Integer, ByVal right As Integer)

    Dim temp As Integer

    Do While left <> right

        Do While (a(left) <= a(right)) And (left <> right)
            left = left + 1                
        Loop

        temp = a(left)
        a(left) = a(right)
        a(right) = temp

        Do While (a(left) < a(right)) And (left <> right)
            right = right - 1                
        Loop

        temp = a(left)
        a(left) = a(right)
        a(right) = temp

        If left <> right
           left = left + 1
        End if
    Loop

    Return left
End Function
```

PS. It could be further optimized to avoid swapping equal elements or swapping the element with itself, I'll leave it for you

Comment: Those modifications are easy enough to do with a simple if-end if that checks if the elements are equal before swapping them or checks if left and right are equal before swapping. But thank you for clarifying the main issue. I was right, it was something obvious I should've caught myself.

Tried it out with just the Do-While comparison modification for the left side and it worked fine with just that. That last If-EndIf seems unnecessary, or am I missing something again?

Comment: @Arcturus do you mean the one that increments "left" iterator? In my version it is necessary, in order to check whether left and right iterators have met or not. If they have met then partitioning has been completed and outer loop should stop, otherwise "left" will be infinitely incremented and will always be different from "right"

Comment: frankly speaking I have never seen this version of partitioning, the canonical version is much simpler and shorter, using a single iterator (either from low to high or from high to low). you may find it even on the wiki page about quicksort